# Custom dialogs like "Create new Test" in IntelliJ? Create class based on class?

Tags: intellij-idea, repository, spring-data-jpa, live-templates, file-templates

"Create new test" dialog in IntelliJ

[image]

automates creation of test classes. Test classes are autogenerated classes, bases on selected ones.

Can I create such dialog of template of my own?

I would like to create classes like this

```
public interface AddressRepo extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {
}
```

where `Address` is the name of original class.

Comment: Yes, you can write a plugin that will show such a dialog and create the classes for you.

Comment: Yes I can write my own `IDE` with such function :)

Comment: Fortunately, writing a plugin requires considerably less effort than writing a full IDE, especially given that you can use the existing "generate tests" functionality as an example.